# How to deal with variables that are too long for html query url?

Tags: html, arrays, url, overflow

I'm developing a multilayered HTML application for data science.

Each layer will contain a step of the process (Dataset selection, parameter selection...), to keep track of the user choice, so for example, if the user selects a particular dataset I save the dataset id in the URL (http://...?dataset='iris'&parameter1=10...). This works wonders for navigation between layers, so for example, if the user would like to change only the dataset I can simply change the URL parameter. Another advantage is that the user can share the state of his work by simply copy-pasting the URL.

However in a part of my application, I ask the user to select a subset of the data from a scatterplot, this wouldn't be a big deal, I can save this information as an array in the URL. However, I have to deal with potentially huge datasets (10000 entries), this overflows the maximum URL capacity and I lose data.

I can avoid saving the information in the URL, but I would lose all the benefits listed above.
Is there a way to save a large array in the URL without it overflowing?
Is there another way around to retain the benefits without saving the parameters in the URL?

(I'm using Flask for the backend and d3.js/Bokeh for the frontend in case this is useful)

Thank you

Comment: Cant you put the selection criteria in the url (instead of the data)?

Comment: Sadly the selection is done manually by the user :c